# Array of objects to file transfer

Tags: java

I need to transfer the data stored in the arrays to a file which in this case I have created as emplo.dat. I cannot find the correct way to do it. Using readObject to transfer the objects is not working since it is an array of objects.

```
import java.io.*;
import employee.*;

public class ClearTechSolutions {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ContractEmployee[] con = new ContractEmployee[3];
        PermanentEmployee[] per = new PermanentEmployee[3];

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
            con[i] = new ContractEmployee();
            per[i] = new PermanentEmployee();
        }

        con[0].setData( "C001", "Mohan", "E-32 M.G Marg", "30/Jun/1974", 0.0f, 1000.0f, 0.0f,     5000.0f, 20, 7);
        con[1].setData( "C002", "Steve", "A-32 M.G. Marg", "15/Oct/1981", 0.0f, 1500.0f, 0.0f,     7500.0f, 22, 3);
        con[2].setData( "C003", "Mary", "A-31 Rohini", "15/Dec/1979", 0.0f, 2500.0f, 0.0f, 10000.0f,     18, 5);
        per[0].setData( "E001", "Bob", "E-12 Lajpat Nagar", "01/Feb/1974", 0.0f, 20000.0f, 0.0f,     800000.0f, 7, 28);
        per[1].setData( "E002", "Kevin", "E-15 Mandir Marg", "01/Apr/1990", 0.0f, 25000.0f, 0.0f,     1000000.0f, 6, 26);
        per[2].setData( "E003", "Mohan", "E-15 Mandir marg", "31/July/1984",0.0f, 10000.0f, 0.0f,     400000.0f,9,30);
        con[0].calc(1000.0f);
        con[1].calc(1500.0f);
        con[2].calc(2500.0f);
        per[0].calc(20000.0f);
        per[1].calc(25000.0f);
        per[2].calc(10000.0f);

        try {
            File file = new File("emplo.dat");
            file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fi = new FileOutputStream(file);
            ObjectOutputStream obj = new ObjectOutputStream(fi);

            for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
                System.out.println("\n");
                System.out.println("The details for Contract Employee "+(i+1)+" are:");
                con[i].print();
            }
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
                System.out.println("\n");
                System.out.println("The details for Permanent Employee "+(i+1)+" are:");
                per[i].print();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: An array of primitives is also an object.

Comment: http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/serialization/index.html

Comment: `Transferring to a file` means writing to a file ?

Comment: I think that is what it means. The problem had that language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    import java.io.*;
    import employee.*;

    public class ClearTechSolutions {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ContractEmployee[] con = new ContractEmployee[3];
            PermanentEmployee[] per = new PermanentEmployee[3];

            for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
                con[i] = new ContractEmployee();
                per[i] = new PermanentEmployee();
            }

            con[0].setData( "C001", "Mohan", "E-32 M.G Marg", "30/Jun/1974", 0.0f, 1000.0f, 0.0f,     5000.0f, 20, 7);
            con[1].setData( "C002", "Steve", "A-32 M.G. Marg", "15/Oct/1981", 0.0f, 1500.0f, 0.0f,     7500.0f, 22, 3);
            con[2].setData( "C003", "Mary", "A-31 Rohini", "15/Dec/1979", 0.0f, 2500.0f, 0.0f, 10000.0f,     18, 5);
            per[0].setData( "E001", "Bob", "E-12 Lajpat Nagar", "01/Feb/1974", 0.0f, 20000.0f, 0.0f,     800000.0f, 7, 28);
            per[1].setData( "E002", "Kevin", "E-15 Mandir Marg", "01/Apr/1990", 0.0f, 25000.0f, 0.0f,     1000000.0f, 6, 26);
            per[2].setData( "E003", "Mohan", "E-15 Mandir marg", "31/July/1984",0.0f, 10000.0f, 0.0f,     400000.0f,9,30);
            con[0].calc(1000.0f);
            con[1].calc(1500.0f);
            con[2].calc(2500.0f);
            per[0].calc(20000.0f);
            per[1].calc(25000.0f);
            per[2].calc(10000.0f);

            try {
                File file = new File("emplo.dat");
                file.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fi = new FileOutputStream(file);
                ObjectOutputStream obj = new ObjectOutputStream(fi);

                for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
                    System.out.println("\n");
                    System.out.println("The details for Contract Employee "+(i+1)+" are:");
                    con[i].print();
obj.writeObject(con[i]);                <-- this will write your object to file connected to file output stream.
                }
                for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
                    System.out.println("\n");
                    System.out.println("The details for Permanent Employee "+(i+1)+" are:");
                    per[i].print();
obj.writeObj(per[i]);
                }
            }
            catch(IOException e) {}
        }
    }
```

to read from file

```
ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(fin);
 abc temp; 
  while((temp=(abc)ois.readObject()))
{
  System.out.println(temp);
  }
```

here abc is class name whose object you want to retrieve. fin in file input stream object.

Comment: Oh forget to mention..
Your class must implement Serializable to use the serialization concept.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by ethrbunny you should probably learn more about serialization.

For the problem in question, you should

1. ensure that the classes ContractEmployee and PermanentEmployee both
   implement Serializable interface.
2. with the ObjectOutputStream "obj"
   instance that you created, call `obj.writeObject(con)` or
   `obj.writeObject(per)` to write the require data held in the array
   into the file.

Note that you wrote an array of objects to the file and not the individual objects one by one. So expect to also get back an array of objects while de-serializing.